# get form data by click and chart with the data in highchart

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I want to load form data and send it to the sever then chart with the returned data. It works fine if the form's input field have default data and I comment

```
//$("button").click(function(){
```

I get no chart all if the default text fields are empty. I tried different ways but still I wont get it load from the form by clicking a button. I am stuck for 2 days now. Please, help. Thanks in advance. Here is the code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var chart = null;
var dataString = [];
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function() {
        $(function() {
            var city1 = $("#city1").val();
            var city2 = $("#city2").val();
            dataString = {
                city1: city1,
                city2: city2
            };

            requestData();
        });
    });

    function requestData() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'array.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: dataString,
            success: function(point) {
                var chartSeriesData = [];
                var chartCategory = [];
                $.each(point, function(i, item) {
                    var series_name = item.name;
                    var series_data = item.data2;
                    var cagory = series_name;

                    var series = {
                        name: series_name,
                        data: item.data2
                    };
                    chartSeriesData.push(series);
                    chartCategory.push(series_name);
                });
                chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                    chart: {
                        renderTo: 'container',
                        defaultSeriesType: 'column',
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'Real time data from database'
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        categories: chartCategory
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        minPadding: 0.1,
                        maxPadding: 0.1,
                        title: {
                            text: 'Value',
                            margin: 40
                        }
                    },
                    series: chartSeriesData
                });
            },
            cache: false
        });
    }
});​
</script>
```

Here is the body section

```
<body>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 200px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

<div id="city_form">
  <form name="contact" action="" method="post">
      <label for="city1" id="city1_label">First city</label>
      <input type="text" name="city1" id="city1" size="30" value="Amsterdam" />


      <label for="city2" id="email_label">Second city</label>
      <input type="text" name="city2" id="city2" size="30" value="London" />
      <button>Click me</button> 
  </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The `$(function()` inside the click function doesn't need to be there..  it's just the shorthand version for `$(document).ready(function()`

Comment: Thanks Wirey. I have removed it and changed it to $(function() {
$("button").click(function(){ but still it doesn't work

Comment: I am starting to wonder if it's possible to even use button click in hichchart! Because I have used  $("button").click(function(){ and  $("button").submit(function(){ to fire the chart function but I always get blank page

Comment: you need to spend some time with jquery before jumping to highcharts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing a bunch of things incorrectly here, one as pointed out by wirey, other you have to prevent the form submission on click of the button. Eh? When you click the submit button, its default action is to submit the form and take you to the `action` page. You do have an added eventListener attached, which makes this ajax call and then plots the chart, but the button will still perform its default action, viz. take you to the `action` page, which in you case is the same page, so you don't even realize that such a thing happened, you may have noticed a flicker or page reload?

jQuery allows preventing this default action by calling the `preventDefault()` method on your event object, which gets passed to you event listener as the 1st argument. You can read more about it here http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/
Try this and let us know if it helped.

HTML

```
<div id="city_form">
  <form name="contact" action="" method="post">
      <label for="city1" id="city1_label">First city</label>
      <input type="text" name="city1" id="city1" size="30" value="Amsterdam" />


      <label for="city2" id="email_label">Second city</label>
      <input type="text" name="city2" id="city2" size="30" value="London" />
      <button id="btnGet">Click me</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

JS

```
$("#btnGet").click(function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    var city1 = $("#city1").val();
    var city2 = $("#city2").val();
    var dataString = {
        city1: city1,
        city2: city2
    };
    requestData(dataString);

});
```

jsFiddle @ http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/V5zt9/6/

Comment: Thanks Thakkar for your answer. I must admit that I am new in jax. I have tried your answer above but no success. I have however tried

Comment: I have however tried                $(function() {
  $('#city_form').on('click', function() {   
   var city1 = $("#city1").val(); 
   var city2 = $("#city2").val();
   
   dataString={city1 : city1, city2: city2};
   
   requestData();   
  });
 })  and it worked but as you can see, its responding to all clicks on the div not only on the button. I appreciate your contributions!

Comment: that is because you are using $("#city_form'), give your button an id, and use that for subscribing to click event, check my updated answer, also @ http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/V5zt9/6/

Comment: Yes, yes, that did the trick. I don't know why the  $("button").click(function() { is not working but definitely $('#button_id').on('click', function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault(); is working perfectly. Jugal Thakkar you are great => I mess up my codes a lot because this is my first hands on ajax,highchart. Thanks a lot for being part of my project. Am looking forward for your continues help!

Comment: I rechecked your first solution and it worked. I can't figure out what I did wrong in regards to executing your solution. Perhaps, it could have being an unenclosed bracket some where. But all in all, your preventDefault(); action of the button was the medicine. Thanks

Comment: Glad to be helpful, still like mina commented, get your hands clear on jquery asap

Comment: I will do that. Thanks for all your recommendations